# Common ground on both input and output of the buck modules

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, low-power

I'm trying to power an Arduino and an ESP32 at the same time, and I made a charging circuit using a MT3608 and a MP1584EN as step up and step down for the Arduino and the ESP32 respectively. As you can see, I grounded both the input and output of MP1584EN module, but I feel weird about this, am I doing things right?

[image]

Comment: The MT3608 is a chip and, it has a data sheet: https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf. I have no clue what your is. If you are using modules then a data sheet and schematic for the module is required.

Comment: is this exact one :https://www.makerfabs.com/adjustable-mini-dc-dc-module-mp1584en.html

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the module? If you have the module, try measuring the resistance between the grounds.

Comment: Page 1 of the IC's datasheet shows a power ground (triangle with lines), which is shared by both the input and output of the module (see the grounds for C1 and C2). The datasheet also shows a signal ground (empty triangle on R6). The two grounds are tied together at Pin 5. Since the IC really only has one ground, i'm guessing that the people who made the module tied the grounds together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module is a buck converter the input and output ground pins are already connected internally. Connecting them on the board isn't necessary but is a good idea.

By the way, for future reference, it is standard to draw circuits from left to right, similar to how words on a page flow. Top to bottom them 90 degree turn to the left makes the diagram hard to understand.